# C sharp with Xamarin - error MT4116

Tags: xamarin

Do anybody know about this problem ?

error MT4116: Could not register the assembly 'Xamarin.Auth.iOS'

My Application suddenly crashed and cannot deploy after, any one can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in the components (not sure when the updates will be available).

The new registrar are doing a lot more error checking (than before) and will now catch such issues - in this case two managed types want to register the same name to the objective-c runtime.

And according to what i hear, this error has been fixed in v 1.1.1..
if you are somewhere below that, try upgrading.

Here's a link : http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15577/xamarin-ios-7-2-1-introduces-managed-type-conflict-between-xamarin-auth-and-xamarin-social

Cheers. Hope this helped.